# Is there a way to use font awesome in marp slides?

Tags: font-awesome, slideshow, marp

Everything is in the question. I wonder if there is a easy way to include font-awesome icons/character into a slide deck using marp ? For example using an inline and local marp directive ?

On a more general point of view, is there an easy way to add arrows or things like that in the presentation?

Answer (score 0):

I once managed to get icons included using the following line of code, which needs to be placed after the `</style>`-tag.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8b20b734d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

FA-Icons can then be included in your markdown text using `:fa-flag:` for instance.

However, with the latest version of font awesome and/or marp-cli, this solution stoped working – at least for me, but it might help others.